# How to retrieve data using xml

Tags: xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<MasterDetailsResponse xmlns="http://192.168.100.173/ArvindMill/">
<MasterDetailsResult>
<GetAllMasterDetail>
<TABLENAME>item_master</TABLENAME>
<ITEMID>1</ITEMID>
<ITEMTYPE>CTS</ITEMTYPE>
<GROUP />
<VARIETY />
<FORM />
<STATUS />
<ITEM />
<GRADE />
<TYPE />
</GetAllMasterDetail>
<GetAllMasterDetail>
<TABLENAME>item_master</TABLENAME>
<ITEMID>2</ITEMID>
<ITEMTYPE>AGS</ITEMTYPE>
<GROUP /><VARIETY />
<FORM />
<STATUS />
<ITEM />
<GRADE />
<TYPE />
</GetAllMasterDetail>
<GetAllMasterDetail>
<TABLENAME>tablet_taluka_master</TABLENAME>
<VILLAGE>Anturli</VILLAGE>
<TALUKA>Anturli</TALUKA>
<TABLETUSERCODE />
<TABLETUSERNAME /><TABLETCODE />
<TABLETTALUKAID />
</GetAllMasterDetail>
<GetAllMasterDetail>
<TABLENAME>tablet_taluka_master</TABLENAME>
<VILLAGE>Bortha</VILLAGE>
<TALUKA>Sadgavan</TALUKA>
<TABLETUSERCODE /><TABLETUSERNAME />
<TABLETCODE />
<TABLETTALUKAID /></GetAllMasterDetail>
<GetAllMasterDetail>
<TABLENAME>tablet_taluka_master</TABLENAME>
<VILLAGE>Kukarmunda</VILLAGE>
<TALUKA>Kukarmunda</TALUKA>
<TABLETUSERCODE />
<TABLETUSERNAME /><TABLETCODE /><TABLETTALUKAID />
</GetAllMasterDetail>
```

The above code is the response returned from soapobject in android. How to retrieve the data from the above XML file? I want to display it in list view and the response returned from the soapobject contains more than one table so how to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Java use SAX Parser